# HTML5 Sortable and Ember.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to make a sortable list using Ember.JS and [this small jQuery + HTML5 plugin](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/).
The problem I'm facing is that moving elements in my list is messing up with the METAMORPH system (I think), leading it to strange behaviors.

My solution was to add an event when the order changed and serialize the new order, make a new list out of it and set it as the content of my array. This works, rerendering the whole list, but

1. rerendering the whole list is heavy
2. strangely, when sending an action (like clicking a button) it now triggers the action twice, and I have no idea why.

Has anyone recently deal with this situation? I'm aware that there are some questions/answers on this particular subject here, but most of them are totally outdated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I've done using `Sortable` from jQueryUi.

```
App.SortableView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement : function(){
    $( "#layerList" ).sortable({
      update: function(event, ui) {
        var indexes = {};
        // create a hash of layer ids and positions
        // { idX : pos1, idY : pos2, ...  }
        $(this).find('.layer').each(function(index) {
          // object id is stored in DOM in the data-id attr
          indexes[$(this).data('id')] = index;
        },this);
        // pass the hash to the controller to update the models
        controller.updateSortOrder(indexes);
      }
    });
  }
});

App.SortableController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  updateSortOrder: function(indexes) {
    // Let Ember know that things are about to change
    this.propertyWillChange('content');
    var layers = this.get('content');
    // Update each layer with the new position
    layers.forEach(function(item) {
      var index = indexes[item.get('id')];
      item.set('position', index);
    });
    // Let Ember know that changes are finished
    this.propertyDidChange('content');
  }
});
```

EDIT : I revisited this issue today when trying to nail down some funkiness in one of my apps.  I ended up putting together a jsbin that demonstrates this functionality.

http://jsbin.com/EZulAN/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hey! Thank you for this solution, it looks pretty straight forward, I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Hey @BenjaminNetter, just wanted to let you know that I edited my answer.  I changed it from `$(this).find('.layer').each(function(index) {...});` to `$(this).find('.layer').each(function(index) {...},this);` (added `,this`) to ensure the proper context for `this` within the `forEach` loop.